# python file content replacement with regex and start of the line problem

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

with open(inputfile,"r") as file:
    content=file.read()
    print(re.sub(r'^(?:[^\|]*\|){38}([^\|]+)','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', content,  flags = re.MULTILINE|re.S))
    file.close()
```

I try to replace a specific part of the log. re.sub function set the end of the line character \n
The logline is broken.

input:

> |Fri Dec 13 05:18:07 UTC 2019||STAAAAAAEC||||||0
>   DA2AAAAAC|00000000000000
>   000000000|SAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAtry|BusAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALog|||||IAAAAAAAAAA01|AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP|||||||||||||||||B7AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA71||iAAAAAAAAAAAA01|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||DAAAAAAAAAro||Sng||PrAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAeter||||||||||||3000|||||||||||||||||||||173||ByAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAed||||Bys|||||UpdAAAAAsk|||||i3taAAAAAA01||||RSM13000||||IAAAAAA01|||IAAAAA01||AP|||AP||||Fri
>   Dec 13 05:18:07 UTC 2019|Fri Dec 13 05:18:07 UTC
>   2019||||||CAAAAA2||||IAAAAA1||||AAAAAP|||||||||||||||||  |Fri Dec 13
>   05:18:07 UTC
>   2019||STACCCCEC||||||||Sy|Bus|||||CCCC01|AP|||||||||||||||||B74CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC48527||values|hostname|||||clAAAAAAAor||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||500||ByAAAAAAed||||Bytes|||||RAAAC|||||iAAAAAA1||||RAAAC||||IAAAAA1|||IAAAAAAAA01||AAAAAAP|||AAAAAP||||Fri
>   Dec 13 05:18:07 UTC 2019|Fri Dec 13 05:18:07 UTC
>   2019||||||HCLAAAAATE||||IAAA01||||AAAAP|||||||||||||||||

expected output:

|Fri Dec 13 05:18:07 UTC 2019||STAAAAAAEC||||||0 DA2AAAAAC|00000000000000 000000000|SAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAtry|BusAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALog|||||IAAAAAAAAAA01|AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP|||||||||||||||||B7AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA71||iAAAAAAAAAAAA01|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||DAAAAAAAAAro||Sng||PrAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAeter||||||||||||3000|||||||||||||||||||||173||ByAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAed||||Bys|||||UpdAAAAAsk|||||i3taAAAAAA01||||RSM13000||||IAAAAAA01|||IAAAAA01||AP|||AP||||Fri Dec 13 05:18:07 UTC 2019|Fri Dec 13 05:18:07 UTC 2019||||||CAAAAA2||||IAAAAA1||||AAAAAP||||||||||||||||| 
|Fri Dec 13 05:18:07 UTC 2019||STACCCCEC||||||||Sy|Bus|||||CCCC01|AP|||||||||||||||||B74CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC48527||values|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|||||clAAAAAAAor||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||500||ByAAAAAAed||||Bytes|||||RAAAC|||||iAAAAAA1||||RAAAC||||IAAAAA1|||IAAAAAAAA01||AAAAAAP|||AAAAAP||||Fri Dec 13 05:18:07 UTC 2019|Fri Dec 13 05:18:07 UTC 2019||||||HCLAAAAATE||||IAAA01||||AAAAP|||||||||||||||||

output:
as you see the line is broken before XXXX

> |Fri Dec 13 05:18:07 UTC 2019||STAAAAAAEC||||||0
>   DA2AAAAAC|00000000000000
>   000000000|SAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAtry|BusAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALog|||||IAAAAAAAAAA01|AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP|||||||||||||||||B7AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA71||iAAAAAAAAAAAA01|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||DAAAAAAAAAro||Sng||PrAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAeter||||||||||||3000|||||||||||||||||||||173||ByAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAed||||Bys|||||UpdAAAAAsk|||||i3taAAAAAA01||||RSM13000||||IAAAAAA01|||IAAAAA01||AP|||AP||||Fri
>   Dec 13 05:18:07 UTC 2019|Fri Dec 13 05:18:07 UTC
>   2019||||||CAAAAA2||||IAAAAA1||||AAAAAP||||||||||||||||| 
>   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|||||clAAAAAAAor||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||500||ByAAAAAAed||||Bytes|||||RAAAC|||||iAAAAAA1||||RAAAC||||IAAAAA1|||IAAAAAAAA01||AAAAAAP|||AAAAAP||||Fri
>   Dec 13 05:18:07 UTC 2019|Fri Dec 13 05:18:07 UTC
>   2019||||||HCLAAAAATE||||IAAA01||||AAAAP|||||||||||||||||

Comment: Please provide example input and expected vs. actual output to show the problem more clearly. What exactly is "broken"?

Comment: If you mean the text matched spans across several lines, add `\n` to each negated character class, `[^|]` > `[^|\n]`. Note you do not need to escape `|` inside a character class. Also, `re.sub` does not "set the end of the line character", your replacement string has no newline in it.

Comment: sample input and expected log is also added

Answer (score 0):

> with open(inputfile,"r") as file:
>       content=file.read()
>
> ```
> mat = re.match(r'(^(?:[^\|]*\|){38})([^\|]+)(.*\n)', content,flags = re.MULTILINE|re.S)
> print(mat.group(1)+" XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"+mat.group(3))
>
> file.close()
> ```

I find another solution where I use the group function.

thanks